# $P(A \cup B) = 0.6$ and $P(A \cup B_c) = 0.4333333,$ where $B_c$ is $B$'s complement. Find $P(A)$.

Tags: probability

$P(A \cup B) = 0.6$ and $P(A \cup B^c) = 0.4333333,$ where $B^c$ is $B$'s complement. Find $P(A)$.

I tried solving it like this:-

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ -- (1)

$P(A \cup B^c) = P(A) + P(B^c) - P(A \cap B^c)$ -- (2)

We know $P(B) + P(B^c) = 1$ and $P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) = P(A)$.

Adding (1) and (2) we get,

$P(A \cup B) + P(A \cup B^c) = 2P(A) + P(B) + P(B^c) - ( P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^c) )$

$\Rightarrow P(A\cup B) + P(A\cup B^c) = 2P(A) + 1 - P(A)$

$\Rightarrow P(A \cup B) + P(A \cup B^c) = P(A) + 1$

Putting values of $P(A \cup B)$ and $P(A \cup B^c)$, we get,

$P(A) = 0.0333333$

But the correct answer is $0.0166667$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note:  your computations would appear to show that $P(A\cup B)+P(A\cup B^c)=P(A)+1$ so $1.0\overline 3=P(A)+1$ which would imply that $P(A)=.0\overline 3$.  One tenth of what you said (and exactly twice the official answer).

Comment: Oh, I put it wrong. I got 0.0333 only. Editing it.

Comment: Note:  I do not understand the close vote (unless it was for the lack of formatting).  The question itself looks solid.  The OP has included a full solution which appears to be carefully thought out.    At least, I don't see anything wrong with it on its face.

Comment: As a minor variant:  write $A$ as the disjoint union of $A_1=A\cap B$ and $A_2=A\cap B^c$.  Then $P(A\cup B)=P(A_2)+P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A_1)+P(B^c)$.  Adding we get $1.0\overline 3=P(A)+1$ which, again, implies $P(A)=.0\overline 3$

Comment: Yes. I also used Venn diagrams and was still getting P(A) = 0.333333

Comment: I don't see any error.   I expect there is a problem with the official solution.

Comment: To stress, it's easy to construct examples.  Suppose that $P(B)=.6$ and that $A$ is a subevent of $B$ with $P(A)=.0\overline 3$   In that case it is easy to verify that, indeed, $P(A\cup B^c)=.4\overline 3$ as desired.